# Kafka Streams - groupByKey returns unexpected result

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka topic t1 than contains 100 messages. After a flatMapValues() operation, the result is written to a second topic t2. 
When I run the following:

```
int count = 0;
t2.groupByKey().count().toStream().foreach((key, value) -> System.out.println(++count));
```

The final value of count is 100, which what was expected.

However, when I apply the same logic on a topic with 500 messages (flatMapValues() + writing to another topic + grouping by key), the final value of count is slightly bigger than 500. 
The gap gets larger with a topic with 10K messages.

What could be the problem ?

Comment: Why do you count twice? Should the `foreach` not print `System.out.println(value)`?

Comment: I'm not counting twice @MatthiasJ.Sax, i'm counting the number of records in the resulting stream by incrementing the value of the variable 'count'

Comment: Ok, "twice" was not the right term. Why are you counting in two places in parallel? -- Also, if you do a flatMapValues() can it be that you emit more record than input records? And if not, why do you not use mapValues() ?

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax yes flatMapValues() emits more records for sure, that's why groupByKey() is supposed to return the exact same number of records before flatMapValues(). the count() is just a dummy call to an aggregation function on the KGroupedStream to obtain a KTable and a KStream afterwards.

Comment: From you original question, it seems that you call `stream.flatMapValues().groupByKey().count()`... Maybe you can share the whole code? I assume that there are not failures? Note, that Kafka guarantees at-least-once processing by default.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax the whole code follows that same exact flow you mentioned: stream.flatMapValues().groupByKey().count() . The code doesn't fail on records that all have distinct keys (in which case groupByKey().count() is a KTable with all values set to 1)

Comment: If you count after the flatMap, it's expected that you count more records than input record, because you count the number to output records from flatMap.

Comment: The groupByKey() should return as many distinct keys in the stream. If we start with 100 records and do a flatMapValues(), grouping by key brings us back to the first state (before flattening). In my example, I'm counting after [ flatMapValues() + groupByKey() ]

Comment: That is not how it work. If you have two records for the same key, `count()` emits two count-records `<key,1>` and `<key,2>` because the result is continuously updated. Please read the docs for more details: https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/memory-mgmt.html

Answer (score 0):

Your problem should be solved in case there are any duplicates because of the at least once implementation. try setting the configuration to exactly once and i'm guessing that will solve your problem. This will guarantee that your each record will be processed exactly once.